# How do I disable the touchpad when the lid is twisted or closed?

Tags: command-line, touchpad, tablet, acpi, events

I have Lenovo ThinkPad X230 Tablet with Ubuntu 16.04. It has a [convertible screen](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51mlomDVzKL._SY450_.jpg) and when it is in tablet mode the touchpad is still active and make a mess.

I've created the following script and bound it to [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2KBe.jpg) of the built in buttons (by a [custom shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/a/591605/566421)):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

# Find the TouchPad device ID
ID="$(xinput | grep -ioP 'touchpad.*id=\K[0-9]*')"                                  

if   [ "$(LANG=C xinput --list-props "$ID" | awk 'NR==2{print $4}')" == "0" ]; then 
        # If the device is disabled, then enable it and kill 'onboard' virtual keyboard
        xinput enable "$ID"; killall onboard; xrandr -o normal
elif [ "$(LANG=C xinput --list-props "$ID" | awk 'NR==2{print $4}')" == "1" ]; then
        # If the device is enabled, then disable it and run 'onboard' virtual keyboard
        xinput disable "$ID"; nohup onboard >/dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

The script works properly, but this is a fake solution and yesterday I spent few hours to learn how to do that in a proper way. So I decided to share this experience here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether the device is in tablet mode or not we could read the value (`0` or `1`) of:

```
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/hotkey_tablet_mode
```

This value is switched by specific events. We can catch these events and could bind scripts to them by using [`acpid`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/acpid.8.html) - Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon.

---

**1.** Catch the events. Execute `acpi_listen` or `netcat -U /var/run/acpid.socket`, turn the lid in tablet mode, then turn it back. Here is an example output:

```bsh
$ acpi_listen
video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000001
video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000000
```

Please note when the lid is close/open the result is different:

```bsh
$ acpi_listen
button/lid LID close
button/lid LID open
```

---

**2.** Configure `acpid` to recognize the events triggered by the device mode change. Run the following lines into a terminal as (single) commands:

```bsh
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/acpi/events/thinkpad-tablet-enabled
# /etc/acpi/events/thinkpad-tablet-enabled
# This is called when the lid is placed in tablet position on
# Lenovo ThinkPad X230 Tablet

event=video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000001
action=/etc/acpi/thinkpad-touchpad-twist-mode.sh 1
EOF
```

```bsh
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/acpi/events/thinkpad-tablet-disabled
# /etc/acpi/events/thinkpad-tablet-disabled
# This is called when the lid is placed in normal position on
# Lenovo ThinkPad X230 Tablet

event=video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/thinkpad-touchpad-twist-mode.sh 0
EOF
```

The above commands will create the files:

- `/etc/acpi/events/thinkpad-tablet-enabled`
- `/etc/acpi/events/thinkpad-tablet-disabled`

Note: The scripts for lid open/close aren't provided here. But they are similar as the above.

---

**3.** Restart `acpid` so it can re-read the event filters, including the ones you just added:

```bsh
sudo systemctl restart acpid.service
```

---

**4.** Create the script `/etc/acpi/thinkpad-touchpad-in-twist-mode.sh` that will disable `1` and enable `0` the touchpad (`&&` make it executable):

```sh
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/acpi/thinkpad-touchpad-twist-mode.sh && sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/thinkpad-touchpad-twist-mode.sh
#!/bin/sh
LANG=C                                                                                                        # Ensure stable parsing
export DISPLAY="\$(w | awk 'NF > 7 && \$2 ~ /tty[0-9]+/ {print \$3; exit}' 2>/dev/null)"                      # Get and export the current user's \$DISPAY
export XAUTHORITY="/home/\$(w | awk 'NF > 7 && \$2 ~ /tty[0-9]+/ {print \$1; exit}' 2>/dev/null)/.Xauthority" # Get and export the currentuser's \$XAUTHORITY
ID="\$(xinput | grep -ioP 'touchpad.*id=\K[0-9]*')"                                                           # Find the TouchPad device ID

if   [ "\${1}" -eq 0 ]; then xinput enable "\$ID"   # Laptop mode or Lid is open
elif [ "\${1}" -eq 1 ]; then xinput disable "\$ID"  # Tablet mode or Lid is closed
fi
EOF
```

- The script will parse and export the environment variables `$DISPAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` of the current user's session, in order to allow `root` (who runs the `acpid` process) to access the user's X session, respectively `xinput`.
- Then the script will parse the `$ID` of the touchpad. And depending on the value of the input variable `$1` it will enable or disable the touckpad.

Note: The backslashes before the dollar signs `\$` are intended to escape the variable (command substitution) expansion within the `cat` command. So if you copy/paste the script (instead using of the `cat` approach) you should remove them manually.

---

References:

- ArchWiki: [`acpid` - Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid)
- Ask Ubuntu: [How do I disable the touchpad while the lid is down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91534/disable-touchpad-while-the-lid-is-down)
- ThinkWiki: [Installing Ubuntu 12.10 on Thinkpad Twist](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Installing_Ubuntu_12.10_on_Thinkpad_Twist) | [Thinkpad-acpi](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thinkpad-acpi) | [Wacom Tablet Stilus](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Wacom_Serial_Tablet_PC_Stylus)
- Ubuntu Forums: [Touchpad ON/OFF](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1635686) | [Why won't this acpi event work?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184296)
- About the parsing read: [Programmatically find the current value of DISPLAY using `w` and `awk`](https://askubuntu.com/a/744751/566421) and [Remove particular words from lines using `grep -P '\K'`](https://askubuntu.com/a/968035/566421).

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer of pa4080, I had to make this change for it to work in Ubuntu 18.04: hard code my user (`tim`) in the script and run the script in the context of my user.

File `/etc/acpi/events/thinkpad-lid-event`:

```
event=button/lid.*
action=su tim -c '/home/tim/scripts/lid.sh.post'
```

and `lid.sh.post`:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
# toggle touchpad enabled status when lid changes (lid closed,touchpad off)
# is run in user context
# 
# example rule /etc/acpi/events/thinkpad-lid-close
# event=button/lid.*
# action=su tim -c '/home/tim/scripts/lid.sh.post'  
#
# see https://askubuntu.com/questions/91534/disable-touchpad-while-the-lid-is-down
# and https://askubuntu.com/questions/980997/how-do-i-disable-the-touchpad-when-the-lid-is-twisted-or-closed/980999#980999
# this needs an event defined in /etc/acpi/events to call this script when lid status changes
# these variables need to be set to use xinput properly
user="tim"
export XAUTHORITY=$(ls -1 /home/$user/.Xauthority | head -n 1)
export DISPLAY=":$(ls -1 /tmp/.X11-unix/ | sed -e s/^X//g | head -n 1)"

export TouchPadID=$(xinput | grep 'TouchPad' | sed  -n "s/^.*id=\([[:digit:]]\+\).*$/\1/p")
grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
LidClosedResult=$?
xinput set-int-prop  $TouchPadID "Device Enabled" 8 $LidClosedResult
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "for user: $user xinput device $TouchPadID enabled status changed to $LidClosedResult because of LID ACPI event" | systemd-cat
else
  echo "failed to change xinput device $TouchPadID enabled status after LID ACPI event" | systemd-cat
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Made another variation acting on 'lid' and 'tabletmode' and just 2 rules catching the response from the ACPI events (use "%e" in the action, mind the quotes !):

```
#!/bin/bash
# toggle 'touchpad enabled status' off/on when lid changes (lid closed or tablet mode => touchpad off)
# 
# let it act on 2 rules in /etc/acpi/events/: lid-change and tabletmode-change:
# 
#     event=button/lid.*
#     action=/etc/acpi/touchpad-toggle.sh "%e"
#
#     event=video/tabletmode.*
#     action=/etc/acpi/touchpad-toggle.sh "%e"
#


# variables needed to use xinput properly
user1="$(who | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
export XAUTHORITY="$(ls -1 /home/$user1/.Xauthority | head -n 1)"
export DISPLAY=":$(ls -1 /tmp/.X11-unix/ | sed -e s/^X//g | head -n 1)"
export TPdID="$(xinput | grep -ioP 'touchpad.*id=\K[0-9]*')"

if [ "${@}" == "" ]; then
    echo "ACPI event didn't return trigger values." | systemd-cat
elif [ "$user1" == "" ]; then
    echo "ACPI event action didn't find current user." | systemd-cat
else
    false
    if   [ "${@}" == "button/lid LID open" ]; then xinput enable $TPdID
    elif [ "${@}" == "button/lid LID close" ]; then xinput disable $TPdID
    elif [ "${@}" == "video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000000" ]; then xinput enable $TPdID
    elif [ "${@}" == "video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000001" ]; then xinput disable $TPdID
    fi
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "ACPI event: xinput device $TPdID status changed on ${@}." | systemd-cat
    else
        echo "ACPI event failed: xinput device $TPdID status NOT changed on ${@}." | systemd-cat
    fi
fi
```

Enjoy using the script ...

Edit:
$USER doesn't always return a result when used by root ...
So I replaced it using:
user1="$(who | cut -d ' ' -f1)"