# Laptop Not Suspend when Lid Closed "every other time"

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, monitor, tlp

My ubuntu 20.04 laptop used to always suspend wen the lid was closed, UNTIL I plugged in a monitor for the first time. I realized this error AFTER I unplugged the monitor. I think that the monitor has broken Ubuntu.

Current behavior:
It seems like every other time I close the lid, it suspends. It's not exactly every other time, but you get the point.
For times when it DOESN'T suspend, it clearly knows something has just happened because when I open it, some elements in GNOME flash white-ish for a second, as if something refreshed. I am also sure that the screen doesn't turn off because I can see under the lid while it's closed.

Suspension itself still works because I am still able to click the suspend button in one of the buttons in the gnome top bar.

I know that there are other questions on this site about suspension problems, but this is different.

**EDIT:** I also found the file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and it has parameters about laptop lid. I don't know which one is causing the problem, so here is the output of `cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
#This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.


[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

**I installed `tlp` and `tlp-stat` on the same day that I connected a monitor for the first time, so the monitor could possibly have nothing to do with it and the problem could be caused by TLP.** I'm not sure if I should uninstall `tlp` because my laptop battery isn't very good with Ubuntu and tlp saves power. But if you think that it would solve the problem, I will uninstall it.

Another possible problem could be that `systemd` thinks I'm "docked" (from output above: `#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore`) and "`ignore`s" it. I have tried changing `ignore` to `suspend`, but no. It doesn't work.

I think that it is most likely if it thinks it's in a docked state. If this helps, I experimented and I realized that when I close the lid while the monitor is connected, the monitor acts as one screen as if it was the laptop screen. So basically it doesn't suspend when closed & connected to a monitor.

But I am almost certain that it has to do with that monitor.

Ubuntu 20.04

DE: GNOME

laptop: Dell Inspiron 17 3000

Comment: Have you tried to change '#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore' in '#HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend'? Does it have any result if you do? <br>The monitor can't break your Ubuntu. I'm pretty sure it can think that you don't want to suspend though.

Comment: @JoepieEs No, I haven't tried that yet but I will try now.

Comment: @JoepieEs BTW...do you know of any way to check if systemd thinks I'm "docked," because that could also help

Comment: No Alex, sorry.

Comment: Here is a particularly related topic: [How do I disable the touchpad when the lid is twisted or closed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/980997/566421)

Comment: @JoepieEs I have tried your suggestion in the first comment to no avail.