# How do I turn off the backlight on my keyboard? (2011 sony vaio PCG-41217N laptop)

Tags: keyboard, laptop, vaio, sony, keyboard-backlight

This question exists for some other sony vaio laptop models (without answer); I haven't yet seen an answer for the sony vaio PCG-41217N laptop.

[The suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/760134/760090) to execute `xset led off` doesn't disable the backlight. Because this laptop is for work, I don't want to risk installing [third-party software](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vaio-control-ce/?source=navbar).

Looking at [a previous asker's sony vaio work](https://askubuntu.com/q/475711/760090), my `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` gives `VPCSB1AHJ`. I *do* have `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight` and `kbd_backlight_timeout` files. Both are 4.1 kB with only the text '-1' when opened in gedit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to turn off my keyboard backlight by changing the value of the read-only text file "kbd_backlight" to **0** ([originally **-1**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987953/what-values-can-kbd-backlight-files-take)) after opening it in gedit with root access via `sudo gedit /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight` in Terminal.

Please be advised that using `sudo` to open `gedit` is problematic, with multiple recommendations on this site to use `gksudo` instead to properly manage file ownership between user and root. [When I executed `sudo gedit`, I received multiple warnings in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/987972/760090).

Comment: Nice. If you wish I could write an answer how to create keyboard shortcut that changes this value, using script that is executed by sudo without password.

Comment: Yes, please: I would like to assign it to an unused key (maybe even *replace* the key that disables my trackpad...), since the keyboard backlight may sometimes be useful. I stored a memo regarding how to hopefully re-enable the setting, since I lack such a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: What is the version of your Ubuntu?

Comment: 16.04 LTS, 64-bit

Comment: To recover from the issue caused by `sudo gedit` restore the ownership permissions to the content of your user's home directory: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME`. Next time use: `sudo -H gedit` or `sudo -i gedit` or `gksu gedit`. But the better idea is to gain ability to work with `nano` or some other terminal based text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @DBinJP's [investigation](https://askubuntu.com/a/987974/566421) (and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987953/what-values-can-kbd-backlight-files-take)), here is presented a way to the complete solution.

---

**1.** Run the following lines as *single* command (copy them all together and paste in a terminal). This will create a script called `kbdbacklight`, that will be placed in `/usr/local/bin` to be accessible as shell command system wide.

```sh
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/kbdbacklight && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kbdbacklight
#!/bin/sh
KBD_BACKLIGHT="/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight"
read VALUE < "\$KBD_BACKLIGHT"
if   [ "\${VALUE}" -eq '0' ]; then echo '-1' > "\$KBD_BACKLIGHT"
elif [ "\${VALUE}" -eq '-1' ]; then echo '0' > "\$KBD_BACKLIGHT"
else echo "Something went wrong."; notify-send "Something went wrong."
fi
EOF
```

Explanation:

- The command `cat << EOF` will output the next lines until the next string `EOF`. These lines will be piped `|` to the command `tee` that will write them in the file `/usr/local/bin/kbdbacklight`. If this operation is successful `&&` then give executable permissions `chmod +x` to the file. The backslashes `\` will escape the special meaning of `$` sign within the `cat` command.
- In the first two lines, the script will read the value of the file `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight`. Then if the value is `0` it will be changed to `-1` and vice versa.

Now the script must be accessible as shell command. Type `sudo kbdbacklight` end hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will be asked for a password to execute the command as *root* by `sudo`.

---

**2.** Grant permissions to all users to run the command (our script) without password via `sudo`. No matter whether the users belong to the *sudoers* group or not.

> **Note:** Always use the command [`visudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/visudo.8.html) to edit the `sudoers` file to make sure you do not lock yourself out of the system – just in
>   case you accidentally write something incorrect to the `sudoers` file.
>   `visudo` will save your modified file to a temporary location and will
>   *only* overwrite the real `sudoers` file if the modified file can be parsed without errors... [**source**](https://askubuntu.com/a/159009/566421).

For this purpose we will create the file `/etc/sudoers.d/kbdbacklight`. Execute the command:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/kbdbacklight
```

And place the following line as a content of the file. Then save and close the file.

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/kbdbacklight
```

Now all users could be able to execute the command `sudo kbdbacklight` without password.

---

**3.** Create [**custom keyboard shortcut**](https://askubuntu.com/a/591605/566421) and bind the script to a desired key (or key combination).

- Go to **System Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** (tab) → **Custom Shortcuts** (section) → Add new <kbd>+</kbd>.
- In the *Custom shortcut* window type: [*Name*: `kbdbacklight`], [*Command*: `sudo kbdbacklight`]. Click on *<kbd>Apply</kbd>*.
- Click on the *Disabled* label and set the keyboard shortcut key or combination.

---

There should be available other possible solutions based on the data and functionalities of the commands as `lsusb`, `xinput`, `evtest`, `acpi_listen` (`apcid`), etc. Here are few references that could provide useful ideas:

- [How do I disable the touchpad when the lid is twisted or closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980997/how-do-i-disable-the-touchpad-when-the-lid-is-twisted-or-closed)
- [Disable touchpad while the lid is down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91534/disable-touchpad-while-the-lid-is-down/98394#98394)
- [Ubuntu 17.10 laptop doesn't suspend on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983168/ubuntu-17-10-laptop-doesnt-suspend-on-lid-close/985711#985711)
- [GIMP Pressure sensitivity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960261/gimp-pressure-sensitivity/960301#960301)

Answer (score 1):

All works thanks!

I adopted the script from the other [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/988013/566421) for my needs. Now my touchpad works. With little changes, that script works for my keyboard backlight and for my touchpad. Just replace `KBDBACKLIGHT` with `TOUCHPAD` - look the original script above.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
TOUCHPAD="/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/touchpad"
read VALUE < "$TOUCHPAD"  
if   [ "${VALUE}" -eq '0' ]; then echo '1' > "$TOUCHPAD"; notify-send "Touchpad ON" 
elif [ "${VALUE}" -eq '1' ]; then echo '0' > "$TOUCHPAD"; notify-send "Touchpad OFF"
else echo "Something went wrong."; notify-send "Something went wrong."
fi
```

Now on my Sony Vaio the custom shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> works as **on**/**off** switch of the keyboard backlight and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> disable and enable the touchpad. Please pay attention of the `VALUE`s - my laptop's on/off values are `1` and `0` not like in the original script `0` and `-1`. (edit these numbers if not work on your laptop).

Cheers :)

Comment: Could you please try to reformat the text of your answer ? It seems to be missing some punctuation, which makes it hard to read. Also, don't thank people in an answer, that's what comments are for.

Comment: Dear Mr. Robert i dont know how to edit post for super look colorfull script like Yours i try all but not work in block. Even if i try just bold font till i have **example txt** stars add to code. Sorry i dont know what i doing wrong. In that post all looks normal in <code>**example txt**</code> just like this...